# RequireJs define parameters

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-define

In the official guide of RequireJs there's a define example:

```
define(["require", "./relative/name"], function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

The first dependency, "require" is returned and inserted into the first parameter of the function.

Where does the second dependency goes?

Is it for the use of the require function that is executed inside?
What does it return into "mod"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second dependency will be the second parameter like so:

```
define(["require", "./relative/name"], function(require, mod) {
    console.log(mod);
});
```

See: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep